# QT Timers not calling function

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt with Python3.

My `QTimer`s are not calling the function they're told to connect to. `isActive()` is returning `True`, and `interval()` is working correctly. The code below (works standalone) demonstrates the problem: The thread is successfully started, but the `timer_func()` function is never called. Most of the code is boilerplate PyQT. As far as I can tell, I'm using this in accordance with the docs. It's in a thread with an event loop. Any ideas?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        thread_func()


def thread_func():
    print("Thread works")
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(timer_func)
    timer.start(1000)
    print(timer.remainingTime())
    print(timer.isActive())

def timer_func():
    print("Timer works")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
thread_instance = Thread()
thread_instance.start()
thread_instance.exec_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `thread_func` from withn the `run` method of your thread, that means the timer your create in that function lives in that thread's event loop. To start a threads event loop, you must call it's `exec_()` method [from within it's run method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads), not from the main thrad. In your example here, `app.exec_()` never gets executed. To make it work, just move the `exec_` call into the thread's `run`.

An additional problem is that your timer gets destroyed when thread_func finishes. To keep it alive, you must keep a reference somewhere.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        thread_func()
        self.exec_()

timers = []

def thread_func():
    print("Thread works")
    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(timer_func)
    timer.start(1000)
    print(timer.remainingTime())
    print(timer.isActive())
    timers.append(timer)

def timer_func():
    print("Timer works")

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
thread_instance = Thread()
thread_instance.start()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem. Also helped me understand QT code structure in general a bit better.